# OPstack: invalid deploy config: BaseFeeVaultWithdrawalNetwork can only be 0 (L1) or 1 (L2)

Tags: go, ethereum, blockchain

I am going through this docs but encountering a error.

https://stack.optimism.io/docs/build/getting-started/

Before this cmd everything works fine

```
go run cmd/main.go genesis l2 \
    --deploy-config ../packages/contracts-bedrock/deploy-config/getting-started.json \
    --deployment-dir ../packages/contracts-bedrock/deployments/getting-started/ \
    --outfile.l2 genesis.json \
    --outfile.rollup rollup.json \
    --l1-rpc RPC
```

Output

```
t=2023-08-07T15:24:53+0530 lvl=info msg="Deploy config" path=../packages/contracts-bedrock/deploy-config/getting-started.json
t=2023-08-07T15:24:53+0530 lvl=info msg="Deployment directory" path=../packages/contracts-bedrock/deployments/getting-started/
t=2023-08-07T15:24:55+0530 lvl=warn msg="L2OutputOracleStartingBlockNumber is 0, should only be 0 for fresh chains"
t=2023-08-07T15:24:55+0530 lvl=crit msg="Application failed"   message="invalid deploy config: BaseFeeVaultWithdrawalNetwork can only be 0 (L1) or 1 (L2)"
exit status 1
```

I don't know about anything so I tried switching between 1 and 0 in BaseFeeVaultWithdrawalNetwork but it won't work.

How to resolve this ?